# python - ctypes opengl functions loading error (OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000)

Tags: python, opengl, ctypes, access-violation

Im getting an error:

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

While trying to load an opengl function with python `ctypes`,

```
from ctypes import *
gl = windll.opengl32
get_proc_addr_prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(WINFUNCTYPE(c_uint), c_char_p)
get_proc_addr_paramflags = (1, "Arg1"),
get_proc_addr = get_proc_addr_prototype(("wglGetProcAddress", gl), get_proc_addr_paramflags)
glCreateProgram = get_proc_addr(c_char_p(b"glCreateProgram"))
glCreateProgram()
```

I thought it's because i haven't created an opengl context, so i ran this code:

```
from ctypes import *
gl = windll.opengl32
gl.glClear(0x00004000)    #    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT = 0x00004000
```

which worked, but trying this way:

```
from ctypes import *
gl = windll.opengl32
get_proc_addr_prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(WINFUNCTYPE(None, c_uint), c_char_p)
get_proc_addr_paramflags = (1, "Arg1"),
get_proc_addr = get_proc_addr_prototype(("wglGetProcAddress", gl), get_proc_addr_paramflags)
glClear = wgl_get_proc_addr(c_char_p(b"glClear"))
glClear(0x00004000)    #    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT = 0x00004000
```

causes the same error.

Comment: You proably did nmot have a GL context when you queried for the function pointer, so you got NULL instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never creating an OpenGL context. Also if `glCreateShader` is available at all depends on the OpenGL version the context is created for. Why are you using `ctypes` in the first place anyway? There are perfectly fine OpenGL Python bindings that abstract away all of the tedious bookkeeping code for you.

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

```
pip install PyOpenGL
```

Comment: @rizo: If PyOpenGL does give you only OpenGL-1.1 then there's something wrong with your machine. Up to, including OpenGL-2.1 you'd always get the highest OpenGL profile supported. And to load the function pointers manually you have to create a OpenGL context in the first place… and also check that it's actually the version you want.

Comment: @rizo Have you tried updating the drivers for your graphics card? Also, if you really want to do it by hand, you might want to take a look at wrapping glew. However, PyOpenGL already uses ctypes to wrap OpenGL, so you might want to take a look at that. ModernGL is another option for another wrapper.

Comment: @rizo: Can you post the source code of your SDL experiment? I wonder how you deduced, that SDL got you a OpenGL-2.1 context. Because in the end what matters is, what the GL_VERSION string tells you.

Comment: @rizo: I think you misunderstood the SDL2 API. The call `sdl2.SDL_GL_GetAttribute(sdl2.SDL_GL_CONTEXT_…_VERSION, …)` does *not* tell you, which OpenGL version SDL2 got. *It tells you, which OpenGL version SDL2 will __ask__ the operating system for, when creating the next new OpenGL context.* What you actually get maybe a very different version.

Comment: @rizo: To me it looks like, as if you simply don't have properly installed any OpenGL driver at all, and are dropped to the fallback software OpenGL implementation that's been shipping with all Windows versions ever since Windows-NT 4 and Windows-95b. I strongly suggest you head over to the website of your graphics card's GPU vendor, download the latest driver release matching your GPU and install that. *The Windows automatic driver updater is known to skimp OpenGL.*